# Running Select results in error 000210

Tags: arcpy, select, error-000210

I'm trying to run SELECT in order to extract specific features under "CLASS_NAME", but continue getting "ERROR 000210: Cannot create output".

I've searched though other questions with the same error but to no avail.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ERROR+000210

```
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\input"
arcpy.Select_analysis("oldpoly.shp", "C:\output\newpoly.shp", '"CLASS_NAME" = item1,item2,item3')
```

Still getting to know Python and learning how to troubleshoot.

Comment: \n is an escape sequence; for your output use a raw string, as in r'C:\output\newpoly.shp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with T.Wayne's answer, your SQL looks funky as well. You  may want to try:

`"\"CLASS_NAME\" IN ('item1','item2','item3')"`

This SQL will select all features with either `item1`, `item2`, or `item3` as its `CLASS_NAME` field value.

or:

`'"CLASS_NAME" = \'item1,item2,item3\''`

This SQL will select all features with `item1,item2,item3` as its `CLASS_NAME` field value.

If your field type for your sql expression is a string, you need single quotes around the value you are selecting for.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> outPoly = "C:\output\newpoly.shp"
>>> print "'{0}'".format(outPoly)
'C:\output
ewpoly.shp'
>>> 
>>> outPoly = r"C:\output\newpoly.shp"
>>> print "'{0}'".format(outPoly)
'C:\output\newpoly.shp'
>>>
```

This probably explains it best:
https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html